# Can't bind to 'zIndex' since it isn't a known property of 'ng2-dropdown-menu'

Tags: angular

My project was working fine yesterday. When I start running it on morning, it gives me this error.

```
If 'ng2-dropdown-menu' is an Angular component and it has 'zIndex' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ng2-dropdown-menu' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("namicUpdate">
    <ng2-dropdown-menu [focusFirstElement]="focusFirstElement"
                       [ERROR ->][zIndex]="zIndex"
                       [appendToBody]="appendToBody"
                       [offset"): ng:///TagInputModule/TagInputDropdown.html@2:23
    at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1694)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.es5.js:12791)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.es5.js:26994)
    at compiler.es5.js:26913
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.es5.js:26913)
    at compiler.es5.js:26800
    at Object.then (compiler.es5.js:1683)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.es5.js:26799)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.es5.js:26728)
```

this `ng2-dropdown-menu` is in https://github.com/benfoley/angular2-tag-input package.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The component doesn't have an input called `zIndex`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import `{ Ng2DropdownModule }`

```
import { Ng2DropdownModule } from 'ng2-material-dropdown';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        Ng2DropdownModule
    ],
```

also in your component you need to do,

```
import { Ng2Dropdown, Ng2MenuItem } from 'ng2-material-dropdown';
```

also add a input as,

```
@Input() public zIndex = new defaults().zIndex;
```

also upgrade your package **`ngx-chips`**

Comment: Nothing changed.

Comment: check updated answer https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips/blob/81f2ffcaff4450d885d4416b97a9564878ed18fb/modules/components/dropdown/tag-input-dropdown.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

That component does not have an input called `zIndex`, so that won't work.

If you're just trying to set the z index CSS property, you can instead use:

```
 <ng2-dropdown-menu [style.zIndex]="zIndex"></ng2-dropdown-menu>
```